# How to fix Unable to resolve "react-native-screens" from "node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\views\StackView\StackViewCard.js"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, node-modules

I used below command for react app routes.

npm i react-native-router-flux --save

Then i restart npm by "npm start" and get this error

Unable to resolve "react-native-screens" from "node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\views\StackView\StackViewCard.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

How can fix this error? I also updated npm.

This is package.json file

```
         {
          "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
          "scripts": {
          "start": "expo start",
          "android": "expo start --android",
          "ios": "expo start --ios",
          "web": "expo start --web",
          "eject": "expo eject"
         },
         "dependencies": {
           "expo": "~36.0.0",
           "react": "~16.9.0",
           "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
           "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
           "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
           "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
            "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
           },
          "private": true
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used react native official navigation. It really helpful and easy to use.
Visit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

Comment: This is what I used but still getting the same error!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Noticed that package.json in the repo is missing react-native-screens from the dependencies.

npm i react-native-screens

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the new **react-navigation** changes. Doing a npm install right now is installing the latest versions instead of the previous versions

You should clear the cache by removing **`node_module`**, .**`expo`** and **`package-lock.json`** and then reinstall all the packages and start the project by using the following command: **`expo r -c`** which should reset the cache and make the project work again as intended.

[More Info](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-react-native/issues/13)

Answer (score 1):

Installing following two,

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view
npm install react-native-safe-area-context
```

it is work for me

or use,

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

for install 'react-navigation'

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error after upgrading from React Navigation V3 to V4.

Simply doing

```
npm i react-native-screens
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following dependencies.

```
@react-native-community/masked-view
react-native-safe-area-context
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expo install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Comment: Can you please include some description and/or explain how this answers the question?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: 'react-native-screens' lib exposes native navigation container components to React Native. It is not designed to be used as a standalone library but rather as a dependency of a full-featured navigation library.
In this case questioner is  using react-navigation-stack lib which uses 'react-native-screens' lib as dependency , but  he didn't included 'react-native-screens' lib and other libs which are needed by react-navigation lib to work correctly.